# Exception Writing to a queue with the MQ Extendend Transaction Client

Tags: .net, transactions, ibm-mq

I am trying to use the .NET MQ Extended Transaction Client to talk to an existing Queue Manager in our enterprise. I am running on a clean install of Windows 2008 R2 with the Extended Client from the MQ 7.0.1 trial.

My program writes to the queue when I comment out the TransactionScope and the MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT options. With the transaction code I get the following exception on the q.Put() call:

```
MQRC_UOW_ENLISTMENT_ERROR ReasonCode 2354
```

Here is my complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using IBM.WMQ;
using System.Transactions;

namespace MQSeries
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var transOptions = new TransactionOptions();
        transOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;

        string queueManagerName = "MYQUEUEMANAGER";
        string queueName = "MYQUEUE";
        string channelName = "MYCHANNEL";
        string channelInfo = "myserver.com(1418)";

        MQQueueManager qm;

        using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transOptions, EnterpriseServicesInteropOption.Full))
        {
            qm = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, channelName, channelInfo);

            // Set up the options on the queue we wish to open
            int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT;

            var q = qm.AccessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

            // Define a WebSphere MQ message, writing some text in UTF format
            MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage();
            hello_world.WriteUTF("Hello World!");

            // Specify the message options
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // accept the defaults,
            pmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;

            // Put the message on the queue
            q.Put(hello_world, pmo);
        }

        qm.Disconnect();
    }
}
}
```

Note that this program does not have a trans.Complete() call. So, barring the current exception, I would expect the message on the queue to be rolled back with the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be an open issue in the v7 client. My v7 XA client was talking to a v6 Queue Manager:

[IC74808: MQ V7 XA CLIENT APPLICATION FAILS WHILE CONNECTING TO MQ V6 QUEUE MANAGER.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC74808)

> A WebSphere MQ v7 XA client
>   application issues an MQCONN to a
>   WebSphere MQ v6 queue manager. The
>   MQCONN fails during a xa_open with
>   reason code 2046, MQRC_OPTIONS_ERROR.
>   This failure in the MSDTC process
>   causes a UOW_ENLISTMENT_ERROR, which
>   is MQRC = 2354. This also results in
>   the xa_open call failing with a -3
>   (XAER_RMERR).